# How to change the default working environment(directory) of Canopy after setting in installed program?

Tags: python, canopy, working-directory

When I installed the canopy I didn't chose the default working directory seriously, after finishing install, I want to change the default working directory, but can't find how to change it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you delete both the User and System environment directories (wherever you put then) and the file `locations.cfg` in your Canopy configuration directory, you will be re-prompted for the location on next startup. You don't say what your OS is, but for the locations of the configuration directory, see step 5 for your OS in this article:
https://support.enthought.com/entries/23580651-Uninstalling-and-resetting-Canopy

Comment: Thank you very much, but do you think Canopy should have added this function on GUI? T_T

Comment: And after I change it, I press Canopy it can't open, no error just nothing happen.T_T

Comment: Thanks for the GUI suggestion. Yes, this will all be improved later in the year. Regarding nothing happening after you deleted directories, it seems likely that you deleted more than just User, System, and configuration directories. At this point, I suggest doing the complete reset as described in that article, then re-installing.

Comment: Not only that, Canopy can open now, but sometime I turn off it and it can't turn on again, no error, after I restart my computer it can work again..Too sad..

Comment: Please file a feedback / bug report from the Canopy help menu so we can try to see what's happening on your system.